# Adding logging requires changing method signature Cats-Effect?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I'm learning the whole Cats-Effect FP framework, and am wondering about how to best implement logging. I'm struggling with finding an elegant way to use logging in methods that return non-side-effect types, particularly class constructors. For example:

```
case class Limit(name: String, value: Int)

object Limit {
  def max(name: String): Limit = Limit(name, Int.MaxValue)
}
```

Now, if I want to add logging to the construction, which is obviously a side-effect, I would have to change the method signature to something like:

```
object Limit {
  def max[F[_] : Sync](name: String): F[Limit] = {
    for {
      _ <- Slf4jLogger.getLogger[F].debug("Creating max limit.")
    } yield {
      Limit(name, Int.MaxValue)
    }
  }
}
```

Such a change breaks code compatibility, and now every place that uses `Limit.max` needs to be refactored to deal with the type signatures, mapping and/or call `.unsafeRun`. Quite a radical change for something as small as adding a log line.

Is there some way to do this more elegantly? Do I just drop log4cats and use the regular, unsafe SLF4J? Or do I just need to accept that in PF/Cats-Effect world it's safer to just return `F[..]` from everything everywhere, no matter how small or trivial the method is?

Comment: Just don't add useless logging, an utility method shouldn't need logging at all.

Comment: This is a simplified example to keep the code short, the question also applies to things like configured constructors that need to log warnings if the configuration looks suspicious, or simply print it out for debugging purposes.

Comment: For the configuration example, return those warnings as plain values and log them in the calling site; maybe add a helper that does both things but you keep your previous method pure.  For quick debugging, just use `println` - For everything else, serious logging is best handled as any other effect, or you could end up logging in the wrong time or the wrong thing _(this a common error IME)_ - Plus, there is also the argument of prefer tracing over logging; still it would imply returning an `IO` or `F` rather than a plain value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use [log4cats](https://typelevel.org/log4cats/) library. If you use cats-effect, probably your Main class returns IO[Exit] and almost whole your logic wouldn't require any unsafe calls.

But at the same time I saw a lot of projects that uses just a plain logging without wrapping logs inside of IO. It depends on you and/or your team/project. I personally prefer FP way.

I left an example of using log4cats here:

```scala
implicit def logger[F[_]: Sync]: Logger[F] = Slf4jLogger.getLogger[F]

case class Limit(name: String, value: Int)
  
object Limit {
  def max[F[_] : Functor: Logger](name: String): F[Limit] = {
    for {
      _ <- Logger[F].info("Creating max limit.")
    } yield {
      Limit(name, Int.MaxValue)
    }
  }
}
```

build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.typelevel" %% "log4cats-core"    % "2.5.0",  // Only if you want to Support Any Backend
  "org.typelevel" %% "log4cats-slf4j"   % "2.5.0",  // Direct Slf4j Support - Recommended
  // and some backend such as logback or smth
)
```

Comment: I am using log4cats, the `Slf4jLogger` come from that. My question is more about the effort required to rewrite a lot of code when you add logging to method that didn't have one before.

Answer (score 0):

In general - **don't add logging to simple code that's just constructing pure case classes**.

This must use an effect signature because logging *is* an effect - you care about when it happens, and how many times it happens. In order for it to happen at the right time and the right number of times, it has to be worked into the control flow of execution.

In this case, I would recommend, instead of adding logging to what is effectively a class constructor, write the logging as a utility method instead

```
def logConfiguration[F[_]: Logger](foo: FooConfig) = Logger[F].info(s"Using $foo")
```

Then you can incorporate that at the call site that makes sense which *already* is doing control flow and using effects.